# App.Run not working when seeding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was getting "HTTP ERROR 404" error when trying to seed the default users and roles on startup. However, it's working if I removed the seeding codes.

Any idea to make this works?

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IIdentitySeed storageSeed)   
{  
    // [...]

    IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

    using (IServiceScope scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager =
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        RoleManager<ElCamino.AspNetCore.Identity.AzureTable.Model.IdentityRole> roleManager =
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ElCamino.AspNetCore.Identity.AzureTable.Model.IdentityRole>>();

        await storageSeed.Seed(userManager, roleManager,
                app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<ApplicationSettings>>());
        }

    app.Run(services.GetRequiredService<SpaFallback>().RequestDelegate);
}
```

Comment: Can you give more detail of what the problem is? Do you get any exceptions etc ?

Comment: @pmcilreavy I am getting "HTTP ERROR 404" when trying to run and debug the app